# I can't call a javascript function from within PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

**Note**: I tried every means that I could think of, without success. I searched stackoverflow and the rest of the internet but couldn't come up with a working solution. I couldn't find in stackoverflow a question about the exact problem.

I'm making a dummy application using PHP and AngularJS to practice in my spare times. The part of the application I have problem with is that it should get input from a form for the new entry and if successful, it should add the dictionary made from the entry to a general array. (Then, on another page, this array is used to form a table showing the entries, using AngularJS. This part works.)

I get the input from the form and if everything is all right, then it should form a dictionary (this also works), then make a JavaScript function call, which pushes the dictionary to an array of dictionaries. This last part isn't working. I changed the function that's being called so that it only has `document.write(dict);`, which didn't work either. So I think I'm making a mistake in doing the JavaScript function call, but then again, I'm not sure.

This is my code:

```js
//controllers.js
(function(){
    angular
        .module("resumeBase")
        .controller("tabularList", listController);

        function listController() {
            var vm = this;
            vm.data = applicants;
        }

        var applicants = [
            {
                firstname: "Nima",
                lastname: "Bavari",
                evaluation: 5,
                category: "IT & Computers",
                fileLocation: "",
                empConfirmed: "yes",
                confirmDate: "01-01-2017",
                employer: "EnDATA",
                payConfirmed: "yes"
            }, {
                firstname: "Ilkin",
                lastname: "Ali",
                evaluation: 5,
                category: "Design",
                fileLocation: "",
                empConfirmed: "no",
                confirmDate: "",
                employer: "",
                payConfirmed: "no"
            }
        ]

        function applicantFiller(applicant) {
            if (applicant.empConfirmed == "") {
                applicant.empConfirmed = "no";
                applicant.payConfirmed = "no";
            }
        }

        function addApplicant(dict) {
            applicants.push(dict);
            applicantFiller(dict);
        }
})();
```

```html
//addNew.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>resumeBase::Add New Entry</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css" />
    </head><body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/engine.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
        <div id="container">
            <?php
            if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                $targetDir = "resumes/";
                $targetFile = $targetDir . basename($_FILES["resume"]["name"]);
                $uploadFinish = 1;
                $fileType = pathinfo($targetFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                $fname = $_POST["firstname"];
                $lname = $_POST["lastname"];
                $eval = $_POST["evaluation"];
                $cat = $_POST["category"];
                if ($fileType != "doc" && $fileType != "docx" && $fileType != "odt" && $fileType != "pdf") {
                    echo "<pre>Invalid file format!</pre>";
                    $uploadFinish = 0;
                } elseif ($_FILES["resume"]["size"] > 500000) {
                    echo "<pre>File too large! Choose another file.</pre>";
                    $uploadFinish = 0;
                } elseif (file_exists ($targetFile)) {
                    echo "<pre>File already exists! Choose another file or rename file.</pre>";
                    $uploadFinish = 0;
                } else {
                    $uploadFinish = 1;
                }

                if ($uploadFinish == 0) {
                    echo "<pre>File not uploaded!</pre>";
                } else {
                    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"], $targetFile)) {
                        echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["resume"]["name"]) . " uploaded.";
                        $newApplicant = '{firstname: "' . $fname . '",';
                        $newApplicant .= 'lastname: "' . $lname . '",';
                        $newApplicant .= 'evaluation: ' . $eval . ',';
                        $newApplicant .= 'category: "' . $cat . '",';
                        $newApplicant .= 'fileLocation: "' . $targetFile . '"}';
            ?>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            addApplicant(<?php echo $newApplicant; ?>);
                        </script>
            <?php
                    } else {
                        echo "<pre>Error uploading file!</pre>";
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
            <h1>Add New Entry</h1>
            <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="id_firstname" maxlength="20" placeholder="First Name" required="required" />
                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="id_lasttname" maxlength="20" placeholder="Last Name" required="required" />
                <select name="evaluation">
                    <option selected disabled>Give an Evaluation</option>
                    <option value=1>1</option>
                    <option value=2>2</option>
                    <option value=3>3</option>
                    <option value=4>4</option>
                    <option value=5>5</option>
                </select><select name="category">
                    <option selected disabled>Choose Category...</option>
                    <option value="IT & Computers">IT & Computers</option>
                    <option value="Design">Design</option>
                    <option value="Services">Services</option>
                    <option value="Agriculture & Industry">Agriculture & Industry</option>
                    <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
                    <option value="Marketing & Sales">Marketing & Sales</option>
                    <option value="Administrative">Administrative</option>
                    <option value="Medical">Medical</option>
                    <option value="Science & Education">Science & Education</option>
                    <option value="Law">Law</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
                <input type="file" name="resume" id="id_resume" required="required" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="id_submit" value="Upload" />
            </form>
            [<a href="index.php">Search</a>]
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It doesn't give any errors, but it doesn't do anything at all either.

Answer (score 0):

Move JavaScript functions from document ready.

```
//controllers.js
(function(){
    angular
        .module("resumeBase")
        .controller("tabularList", listController);

    function listController() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.data = applicants;
    }

    var applicants = [
        {
            firstname: "Nima",
            lastname: "Bavari",
            evaluation: 5,
            category: "IT & Computers",
            fileLocation: "",
            empConfirmed: "yes",
            confirmDate: "01-01-2017",
            employer: "EnDATA",
            payConfirmed: "yes"
        }, {
            firstname: "Ilkin",
            lastname: "Ali",
            evaluation: 5,
            category: "Design",
            fileLocation: "",
            empConfirmed: "no",
            confirmDate: "",
            employer: "",
            payConfirmed: "no"
        }
    ]
})();

function applicantFiller(applicant) {
    if (applicant.empConfirmed == "") {
        applicant.empConfirmed = "no";
        applicant.payConfirmed = "no";
    }
}

function addApplicant(dict) {
    applicants.push(dict);
    applicantFiller(dict);
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. Thanks. Can you tell me what's the reasoning behind this, Shamil bhai?

Comment: Functions declared inside the $(function() are only accessible within that. If you need to use those outside, window object to make it global.

Comment: Your code doesn't work either. I think, it's because I can't access the array `applicants` from inside the function `addApplicant`... I tried taking the array out as a global, and then it became even worse. What to do?